# Get the sum of a column of dynamic HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I have a dynamic HTML Table which gets update for every 60 seconds through fetching JSON data from external API by Vue.js. As I am developing a simple dashboard, I have cards. So, one of the card has to display the sum of a particular column from my HTML Table.

Also I am having switching buttons to hide rows based on the keyword. So I am trying to fill that card after the particular button clicked,  then I can get the total order of the column for particular orders.

My Vue functions were written as "onLoad" functions, so on page load I get my table filled with data.

But, when I try to get the sum of the total of the column, it throws the error "Row : null" and does not display the message in my card's `<p>` element, but I can see the rows on condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```js
// Show only Paypal orders rows by hidimg cash orders row
$(document).on('click', '#btn1', function() {
  $(".table tr:contains('cod')").hide();
  // Getting the total of the column to display in the card
  var table = document.getElementById("table"),
    sumVal = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML);
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Sum Value =" + sumVal;
});
// Show only cash orders rows by hidimg paypal orders row
$(document).on('click', '#btn2', function() {
  $(".table tr:contains('cod')").show();
  $(".table tr:contains('ppec_paypal')").hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn3', function() {
  $(".table tr:contains('cod')").show();
  $(".table tr:contains('ppec_paypal')").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Cards -->
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="dashbord" id="app1">
    <div class="icon-section">
      <small>Total amount for tdoay Orders</small>
      <p v-for="totalsales, index in totalSales">
        {{ totalsales.total_sales }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashbord dashbord-orange">
    <div class="icon-section">
      <small>Total Amount - Cash By Hand</small>
      <p id="output"> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Blocks Ends-->

  <!--Navigation Buttons - All orders / Paypal / Cash -->
  <div>
    <br> <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1">Paypal Orders</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn2">Cash Orders</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn3">All Orders</button>

  </div>
  <div class="container mt-5" id="app">
    <table class="table table-bordered 2px">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Order id</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Payment</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="order, index in orders">
          <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ order.total}}</td>
          <td>{{ order.payment_method}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your `table` doesn't have `id="table"` which you are using here   `var table = document.getElementById("table")..`

Comment: Also there is no `cells[4]` according to your code  that should be `cells[1]` i.e: `sumVal + parseInt (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)...`  where your `Total` is displayed change that as well it should work .

Comment: Thanks for pointing it. But if i change it to cells[1] then , there wouldn't be no calculations, it throws "NaN". Also if i keep it like cell[4], now it is calculating the whole table sum, not the trimmed table...

Comment: which cells you need to calculate ?

Comment: Actually, the 5th column...

Comment: your table code doesn't have 5th column .. maybe you should update your question with that as well .

Comment: @Swati,, Sorry, i forgot that i just deleted some columns to post here. Yeah you were right, according to here it has to be cells[1]. But one question, why it is giving the sum of whole table, not the trimmed table after button clicked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221776/discussion-between-swati-and-tom).